# flowplayer video in ajax response

Tags: jquery, flowplayer

This comes from an ajax reponse:

```
<div class="flowplayer">
<video controls preload><source type="video/mp4" src="/assets/images/testvideo.mp4"></video>
</div>
```

With a running flowplayer instance on the parent side. However, the new flowplayer class is not recognized, can someone help me out, please?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It looks like in your success callback after your ajax call you will need to reinitiate flowplayer by calling

```
 $('.flowplayer').flowplayer();
```

http://flowplayer.org/docs/setup.html

In addition the "controls" attribute on the video tag doesn't look to be supported by flowplayer. Flowplayer defaults to showing controls and can be removed by using predefined modifier classes on the main div, or hiding them in your css.

http://flowplayer.org/docs/skinning.html